# Could APP development use websocket to achieve real-time scrolling?

Tags: android, ios, websocket

I am developing a set of **APIs for android, ios and web.**

Part of the information needs to be **real-time scrolling**, so I would like to use **websocket as a client and service communication**, is this feasible?

Or are there any better solutions?

If I use websocket, what do I need to pay attention to in terms of security?

Now, TLS have been used for encrypted communication.

Very much looking forward to your answer! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean real time scrolling :/

Comment: @SeanLintern88 For example, if I post a new content, all clients will display a notification like "XXX posted XXX", and all the similar information is real-time scrolling. Does this elaborate?

Comment: ah ok so real time updates, I would edit your post, this is 100% possible with sockets, sockets can connect through SSL so theres no security issue

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Thanks! I can use it with confidence~